# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error 168 when running migrations

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a fresh installation of laravel 7 which I installed through composer, created the database and connected in the .env.
However, when I run migrations, I see the following error:

```
    ➜  laravel-adp-4 git:(develop) ✗ php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error 168 - 'Unknown (generic) error from engine' from storage engine (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

I can confirm that all my services are up:

```
➜  laravel-adp-4 git:(develop) ✗ brew services list
Name      Status  User    Plist
mysql     started macbook /Users/macbook/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
mysql@5.7 started macbook /Users/macbook/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist
nginx     started root    /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php       started root    /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
php@7.3   started macbook /Users/macbook/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php@7.3.plist
```

Trying to troubleshooting I noticed that I can no longer manipulate mysql.
When I try to create another database, I see the following error:

```
ERROR 3680 (HY000): Failed to create schema directory 'alala' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

Why am I not able to run migrations?
Why am I not able to create a database?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is nt ok you have a single quote too much around `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

```
create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) 
default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Keep in mind this is a generated SQL output from the Laravel command `php artisan:migrate`; they cannot modify this query directly as you're suggesting...